# Is ELB draining tcp based?

Tags: session, amazon-web-services, tcp, sticky, amazon-elb

I am facing an interesting problem. We run an HTTPS based application that is state based. State is maintained based on session cookie. The application is designed in such a way that if the session gets terminated abruptly, the application is reverted to home screen any un-saved data is lost. So its very important for us to maintain session.

Some point in the past it was decided to use AWS services for this purpose and the current architecture has an ELB that balances load to an auto-scaling group. The first architecture that was used had HTTP based sticky session enabled. It is found out during testing that when scaling down the existing sessions are getting closed immediately and gets re-routed to available instances. This happens even after enabling draining (time out of 5 mins) which as per documents should prevent this from happening. Could someone please tell me what are we doing wrong and is this the way it is suppose to work?

My second question is, we found out this is not the case when using ELB is used to balance load based on tcp connections. In this case when we scale down old tcp connections are maintained until it gets closed or times-out and new connections are routed to other instances. This is the current setup that we are using. So my question is why ELB behaves differently in both the cases and is there any way to make ELB use HTTP sticky session and drain based on tcp connection?

If you do have an answer please share with config details. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question #1 - this is the expected behaviour of ELB Connection Draining.

From the doc : "Connection draining causes the ELB load balancer to stop sending new requests to a deregistering instance or an unhealthy instance, while keeping the existing connections open. This allows the load balancer to complete in-flight requests made to the deregistering or unhealthy instances."
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#conn-drain

ELB does not know about your session state as this is something managed by your application.  Connection draining only applies at network level. If there is no open connection to your instance, ELB might elect your instance for deregistering from AutoScaling (and auto scaling will later terminate it)

Question #2 : When using TCP mode on the load balancer, it doe snot try to understand the HTTP content (such as cookie) and happily send anything received from the client to backends.  The behaviour you are experimenting might be related to the way the client browser manage connections (i.e. keeps open connection). This has to be verified with a web development tool.

For your use case, I would investigate auto-scaling life cycle events to trigger a piece of code of you when auto scaling will take action on your instance.  Using life cycle events, you have the occasion to trigger custom code at key life cycle states of your instance and to take additional actions or ask Auto Scaling to ABANDON the change.

Details are available here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingGroupLifecycle.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/lifecycle-hook-considerations.html

Comment: "keeping the existing connections open" means the existing tcp connections are kept alive as long as they are not closed by either party right. But when we tested, this is not what is happening. We have keep-alive on HTTP request and the tcp connections are kept open by both the client and server when we test against a stand-alone server. But ELB just closes the connection in spite of draining enabled and using application based session stickiness.

Comment: By default ELB keeps connections open for 60 secs to your clients and to the backend. You can change that value at anytime and specify any value between 1 and 3600 seconds. If you are specifying a keep alive on the backend, and you want the load balancer to be responsible for closing the connection, you have to configure the ELB idle timeout with a lower value than your keep alive

Comment: Connection draining is independent from connection keep alive. Keep alive is a network optimisation to avoid the overhead of opening TCP connections for each HTTP request. Connection draining is about preserving user connection when an instance is going to be removed from the load balancer to avoid interrupting customers HTTP connection in progress. Finally HTTP Sessions are only visible from the application level and are not visible from the ELB (only session cookies are when working on HTTP mode on your ELB)

Comment: So you mean to say that draining in ELB when configured to use HTTP will keep the session open only as long as the current HTTP request is active and the next http request form the same session will still go to a different server. I know i am pushing it but this will be my last question :)

Comment: ELB connection draining is not aware of http session. Closing an http session is an application level event (usually when your user sign out). HTTP  sessions and TCP connections are not related. A user can close its http session at application level while the browser might maintain a TCP connection open or vice versa. ELB connection draining takes care of TCP connections regardless of the state of an http session on your backend.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but in reality based on our testing thats not what is happening. ELB seems to close tcp sessions even when they are active during draining. Thats the reason we switched to tcp based load balancing. Thanks for your reply. This is as good as any answer i can get. Also i looked into lifecycle hooks, seems like we can do something useful with that.

Comment: Thank you - please do not hesitate to post a message on the forum (for free) or to open a support ticket for root cause analysis (developer support - $49/month)